# How can i get data from a sails.js DB server to an android app?

Tags: javascript, java, android, server, sails.js

i have an android app and a server with sails.js. In this server i have a model. I'd like to know how can i get the data in this model from my android app?
I should also filter this data before receiving them in the app.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: This is pretty broad. What is the specific issue?

Comment: i update server and cliient in github repo. This is the java class where i ask for data .https://github.com/imaluris/FalesieInItalia-Client/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/falesieinitalia/ListaFalesie.java

Comment: and this is the server with model named Falesia. https://github.com/imaluris/FalesieInItalia-Server

Comment: i need to know how get data from client to server. When i request data i need to send also some parameters to server. How can i do?

Comment: Are you asking how to make an HTTP request with parameters in Android?

Comment: I already did an HTTP request, but without parameters. I'd like to know how put in the request parameters and how do get this parameters from the Sails.js server correctly.